# submit function - display a warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a warning message when a user types certain text into an input box.  The problem is I only want to return false one time so the user can submit the form on the second click even if they don't change the text.  I've tried adding a counter but jquery is not remembering the count on a second sumbit click.  What is the best way to go about this?

```
if (email.val().indexOf("gmail") > -1)) 
        {
        $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');    
        $("#submit").after('<p>Error - Do you want to use a gmail account?</p>');
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: You may want to look into javascript's `confirm` function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put a class on your text box and remove it in the first failure? Thus when you look for it with jQuery a second time you won't be able to find it it and won't be able to apply the rule. I implmented it like so:

```
var submit = function()
{
    var email = $('.emailFirstTry')

    if (email.length > 0 && email.val().indexOf("gmail") > -1)
    {
        $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');    
        $("#submit").text('Error - Do you want to use a gmail account');
        $('.emailFirstTry').removeClass('emailFirstTry');
        return false;
    } 

    $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','none');
    $("#submit").text('Success!');
    return true;
};
```

You can see it in action on this fiddle right here: http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/39wjbwcr/

Hope the helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flag to determine if they have already tried to submit, and if they haven't, then you give them the warning and return false:

```
var triedSubmit = false;
$(/* Your jQuery Object */).click(function() {
    if (email.val().indexOf("gmail") > -1)) 
    {
            if (!triedSubmit){
                $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');    
                $("#submit").after('<p>Error - Do you want to use a gmail account?</p>');
                triedSubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set up some kind of flag

```
var flags = {}; // in some higher scope
// then later, in your verification function
if (email.val().indexOf("gmail") > -1 && !flags.warnedGmail) {
    $('input[name=email]').css('border-color','red');    
    $("#submit").after('<p>Error - Do you want to use a gmail account?</p>');
    flags.warnedGmail = true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `flags` would go out of scope once the function has been returned. Just note that `flags` would need to be a global variable.

Comment: It doesn't have to be global, just in a higher scope, made it clearer